# INSERT single quoted value for all column types in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Say you have a column of int (also bit, etc.)

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (a int)
```

It seems it doesn't matter if you insert value with '1' or 2

```
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('1')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (2)
```

Is there any side-effect if I insert/update values by single-quoting them (e.g.'value') for any column type?

Comment: use the appropriate type (obviously)

Comment: @MitchWheat thats not answering my question

Comment: Are you asking about costs of implicit type conversion?

Comment: @MitchWheat but I am asking about "side-effect", not best practice!?

Comment: one precludes the other.

Comment: @MitchWheat agree to disagree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server will implicitly convert data types according to data type precedence rules as documented in the Books Online https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx.  Integer has a higher precedence so string literals will be converted to integer in your examples.  The downside is a little more work for SQL Server to do but the overhead probably isn't significant.

However, beware of implicit conversion of expressions in `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses.  If the compared column is indexed and has a lower precedence, the index can't be used efficiently and a scan may be required.  This is a common issue with Unicode literals/parameters and varchar columns.

It's best to match types for maximum performance and to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I will only use this in simple INSERTs, so I will be good in that case. Love your detailed answer. Picked yours.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. This is just bad practice. If you weren't using mysql another db would definitely yell at you and you would be confused. Plus I'm thinking if you loaded a larger dataset it might be slower because of the parse that would have to occur behind the scenes.

Comment: Sorry Mitch. Eyes are getting tired.